# Flutter + Google Maps: How to use an icon from Flutter Icons class as Google Maps marker icon?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

How to use an icon from the Flutter Icons class (NOT an image) as the custom icon for a Google Maps marker? e.g. `Icon(Icons.house)`

This seems like a basic functionality that should be supported, but I haven't been able to find a straight-forward solution. Thanks!

Comment: The core of Google Map is implemented in natively, not in flutter/dart. So there is no easy way to have it display a widget like `Icon`

Comment: You might want to check this out. https://medium.com/geekculture/change-google-map-marker-icon-in-flutter-c68b2e4da31e

Doing a quick google search should fix your concern. :)

To increase your chances of getting help in the future, I recommend that you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Yrll I don't think the article you provided solves this problem. The question states clearly that it is not looking to use an image, but a Material Icon.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. But I guess PurplePolyhedron's comment still applies.\